# Split NSString into multiple UITextView with fixed size

Tags: pdf, uiview, split, export, uitextview

I'm creating an app that exports text to PDF. I have a UIView with the layout of the PDF page, but is only one page. The text doesn't have a maximum length, can be as long as the user wishes.

The problem comes when I want to split the text into multiple pages. Every page has an UITextView (body of the text) and I need put into every UITextView every part of the text.
Every page has a fixed frame and font size on the UITextView.
Any idea?

Thanks!